# In Vista in Administrative Tools the Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration shortcut is gone, how do I view the GAC?

Tags: .net, gac

I'm trying to view the items in the GAC on Vista and I've got all the .NET stuff installed, 1.0, 2.0, 3.5 and 3.5 SP1 but I don't see shortcut from Administrative Tools. Does anyone know another way to view and edit the items in the GAC?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not in front of my home PC with vista, but is there a c:\windows\assembly folder on yours?